# Azure IotHub doesn't receiving any messages

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm just set up my iot hub that should receiving messages from my test device. It work's perfect about one day. On second day when I send messages to this azure service I don't getting any exception but my iot hub doesn't receving any messages. I don't know what is the main problem of that ? Additionaly I have one worker role that handle all messages on event hub processor from this iot hub. Maybe is there any extra settings that stops my iot hub or something more ? I can't find any information on other sites maybe someone have similiar problem ?

Comment: You can use [device explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#monitor-device-to-cloud-events) to monitor messages sent to Azure IoT Hub.

Comment: It doesn't show any message so I don't know how I can debug it for detec issue ?

Comment: Can you use device explorer to send messages to your device?

Comment: And check your iot hub Status in azure portal.

Comment: What do you mean by status ? I look at some options and i have parameter Retention time set to 1 days, that mean it can work only one day ?

Comment: I mean you can check your iot hub status is **Active** or not? **Can you use device explorer to send messages to your device?**

Comment: Yes, I can do this, it works

Comment: Can you show your device connection string format?

Comment: I'm using .Net Sdk Client where i put my iot device id and primmary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding,

1. Your device sends message to IOT Hub
2. Your worker role reads message from this IOT hub using EHP

If this is the case and you are not receiving messages at EHP than **CONSUMER GROUP** could be the issue. Basically, IOT hub serves messages per consumer group. By default each IOT Hub has **$Default** group. If some other service is already reading message from this consumer group than you won't be able to get message.

You can create another consumer group for your worker role. IOT Hub serves same message to each consumer group.